# cakephp and add method (foreign keys)

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-1.3, addition

just starting with cakephp and almost with php after a few years without use it....

I have a table structure like this:
**Parent table......  Clients:**

```
<?php
class Cliente extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Cliente';
        var $validate = array(
                            'nombre' => array('rule'=>'notEmpty')
                             );
        var $hasMany = array(
            'Proyecto' => array(
                'className'  => 'Proyecto',
                'foreignKey' => 'cliente_id',
                'order'      => 'Proyecto.nombre ASC',
                'dependent'  => true                
            )
        );
}
?>
```

**And child table: Proyects..**
A client can have several projects assigned.

```
<?php
class Proyecto extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Proyecto';
        var $validate = array(
                            'nombre' => array('rule'=>'notEmpty')
                             );
        //var $belongsTo = 'Cliente';
        var $belongsTo = array(
            'Cliente' => array(
                'className' => 'Cliente',
                'foreignKey' => 'cliente_id'
            )
        );
}
?>
```

Proyects only can be added (INSERT) from the index client view.  So, I have this add (anadir) method:

```
    function anadir($cliente_id, $nombre) {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
//                        echo "El código de cliente 22222: ". $this->data['Proyecto']['id'] . "</br>";
//                        echo "El código de cliente fk: ". $this->data['Proyecto']['cliente_id'] . "</br>" ;
//                        print_r($this->data);
                        //$this->data['Proyecto']['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id;
            if ($this->Proyecto->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('El proyecto ha sido grabado.');
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'clientes', 'action'=>'listar'));
            }
                } else {  
                        //echo "El código de cliente 11111: ". $this->data['Proyecto']['id'];                  
                    $this->data['Proyecto']['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id; 
                }
                $this->set('idcliente', $cliente_id);
                $this->set('nombrecliente', $nombre);
    }
```

I can show the parent client (id and number) in the 'anadir.ctp' view, but it always update the same proyect, changing the name and description only.   No ADD/INSERT is done in the table, only UPDATE.

```
<!-- File: /app/views/proyectos/anadir.ctp -->  

<h1>A&ntilde;adir proyecto a cliente <?php echo "[$idcliente] - $nombrecliente"; ?></h1>
<?php
    //echo $this->Form->create('Proyecto', array('action' => 'anadir'));
    echo $this->Form->create('Proyecto', array('url' => '/proyectos/anadir/'.$idcliente.'/'.$nombrecliente)); // array('action' => 'anadir'));
    echo $this->Form->input('cliente_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input('nombre');
    echo $this->Form->input('descripcion', array('rows' => '10'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Grabar proyecto');
    echo $this->Html->link('Cancelar', array('controller'=>'clientes', 'action'=>'listar'));
?>
```

Surely it is a newbie question but I have tried almost everything.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

## ====  Finally  ====

After a few days trying to solve this it is running now.  But I cannot understand the problem and I have no explanation why I have had that weird problem...

So I am going to look forward symfony2    Perhaps more difficult to start with but I hope more flexible (with multi Primary Keys and foreign key support, mainly) and clear than cakephp.

Comment: Double-check that `id` exists and is a primary key in `Proyecto` DB table (not `cliente_id`). And just to be sure, put `$this->Proyecto->create();` line before `if ($this->Proyecto->save($this->data)) {`.

Comment: The DB Table is ok (I think).. id is the primary key.  If I put `$this->Proyecto->create();` where you have said then the project is saved ok... with another errors related to function anadir(arg1, arg2) --> Ie: `Missing argument 1 for ProyectosController::anadir() [APP/controllers/proyectos_controller.php, line 18]`   Hummmmm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it still looks (as **deizel** suggested) that you've got `id` set in your `$this->data` somehow, probably a field with mistaken in a form, not sure (you can post your view here so we can take a look). The best way to check it is to monitor actual SQL queries; put this after `$this->Model->save()` (without adding `$this->Model->create()`yet, for debug purposes):

```
$log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
debug($log);
```

Add output of above to your question.

Regarding `$this->Model->create()`: calling it prior to `$this->Model->save()` is perfectly ok and even recommended. It's like variable initialization - you can skip it, but at your own risk, when you're absolutely sure what you're doing.

To address `Missing argument 1 for ProyectosController::anadir()` error you should post your URL here. It should be something like `/proyectos/anadir/2/10`.

Comment: I have added details for the debug($log) on the original question.

Comment: Add logging _after_ saving (i.e. after `$this->Proyecto->save($this->data)`) - currently it does not show any `UPDATE`/`INSERT` queries. But actually this doesn't matter since calling `create()` has fixed your problem.

Comment: Yes.... `create()` has fixed it, but I cannot understand why I have had that problem.  If I put the log after, then I can see it is updating.  :-(

Answer (score 1):

Above Model are same

but change below code and try

```
function anadir() {//add method has not neet parameters
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
       //                        echo "El código de cliente 22222: ". $this-      >data['Proyecto']['id'] . "</br>";
       //                        echo "El código de cliente fk: ". $this->data['Proyecto']['cliente_id'] . "</br>" ;
      //                        print_r($this->data);
                    //$this->data['Proyecto']['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id;
        if ($this->Proyecto->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('El proyecto ha sido grabado.');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'clientes', 'action'=>'listar'));
        }
            } else {  
                    //echo "El código de cliente 11111: ". $this->data['Proyecto']['id'];                  
                $this->data['Proyecto']['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id; 
            }
            $this->set('idcliente', $cliente_id);
            $this->set('nombrecliente', $nombre);
}

<!-- File: /app/views/proyectos/anadir.ctp -->  

<h1>A&ntilde;adir proyecto a cliente <?php echo "[$idcliente] - $nombrecliente"; ?></h1>
 <?php
 echo $this->Form->create('Proyecto');

echo $this->Form->input('Proyecto.cliente_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('Proyecto.nombre');
echo $this->Form->input('Proyecto.descripcion', array('rows' => '10'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Grabar proyecto',array('url'=> array('controller'=>'proyectos','action'=>'anadir'));
cho $this->Form->end();
echo $this->Html->link('Cancelar', array('controller'=>'clientes', 'action'=>'listar'));
?>
```

Comment: I have try this approach and I have a a few warnings: Undefined variables: `Undefined variable: cliente_id [APP/controllers/proyectos_controller.php, line 30]` And on form-post: `Warning (512): SQL Error: 1048: Column 'cliente_id' cannot be null [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]`

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP will perform an update if an ID exists in your data at this point:

```
            if ($this->Proyecto->save($this->data)) { ...
```

Uncomment the following line and check there is no `$this->data['Proyecto']['id']` value:

```
//                        print_r($this->data);
```

Comment: `$this->data['Proyecto']['id']` is empty.  I had checked it previously (that is the reason of the comment `echo` lines).  I have uncomment that line and this is the result: `Array ( [Proyecto] => Array ( [cliente_id] => 3 [nombre] => p17 [descripcion] => p17...x ) ) `

Answer (score 0):

With the comment of @lxa I have get it to run in this way:

Replace `function anadir` with this one (I have remove comments too):

```
function anadir($cliente_id, $nombre) {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
                $this->Proyecto->create();
        if ($this->Proyecto->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('El proyecto ha sido grabado.');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'clientes', 'action'=>'listar'));
        }
        } else {  
            $this->data['Proyecto']['cliente_id'] = $cliente_id; 
        }
        $this->set('idcliente', $cliente_id);
        $this->set('nombrecliente', $nombre);
}
```

Really this line does the trick:

`$this->Proyecto->create();`

It runs but I don't know if it is really right or not.

At last I am starting to see Symfony2.  Perhaps the learning curve will be bigger than cakephp, but cakephp is given me a lot of problems with foreign keys and the way of do on databases.

Greetings and thanks to somebody trying to answer.